# Calling setTimeout function from a variable

Tags: javascript

I have defined a variable for a setTimeout function so that I can clear it later. That part works. I am having problems calling up the setTimeout function from the variable and I think I don't understand the syntax.

```
var idOne = setTimeout(function() {
    //do stuff here
    custom(); //callback
}, 2000);

function custom() {
    //do stuff here
    idOne;
}

custom();
```

Specifically the `idOne;` part I feel like has to be wrong. JsHint is saying it is not doing anything. I can't figure out the syntax.

**EDIT**

Got it! Here is the final code!

```
var idOne;
var timeoutOne = function(){
    idOne = setTimeout(function(){
        //stuff
        custom();
    }, 2000);
}

function custom() {
     //do stuff
     timeoutOne();
}
```

and then when I want to clear it, I use:

```
clearTimeout(idOne);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? the `idOne` variable will just be an int value which is the reference to the timer you've stored. Also, `do` is a reserved keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_6

Comment: `do` is a keyword. That shouldn't work at all. That being said, the return of `setTimeout` is just there to use `clearTimeout` if you decide that you don't want to run the function after all.

Comment: I want the setTimeout to be linked to a variable so i can clearTimeout(variable). I want to run this setTimeout from the variable in the function.

I'm new to this. didn't realize do was used. I will change it.

Comment: What you have will work, you just need to call `clearTimeout(idOne)`. Note however, that your current pattern makes this redundant as the timeout will already have executed before you clear it.

Comment: In my actual js i have the clear linked to an on click command. The problem is it is not running through the  setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the setTimeout function returns a `Number`, which can be used to `clearTimeout`. I guess, what you want to do, is to define a function

```
var myFunction = function () { 
    idOne = setTimeout(function() {
         custom();
    }, 2000);
}

function custom() {
    myFunction();
}

custom();
```

and finally, to `clearTimeout` :

```
clearTimeout(idOne);
```

Comment: would I then be able to clear it with clearTimeout(idOne);?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: in that case, check the update, now you can `clearTimeout(idOne);`

Comment: `cleartimout(idOne)` is only possible because `idOne` is a global variable. When declared, the `var` was left out. this makes the variable an implicit global

Comment: I'm confused how this could work. Basically I need to define a variable as a setTimeout function and run it at the end of another function using that variable so I can clear it remotely with a different function.

The problem I am having is how to launch the setTimeout function via the variable. it seems like what is here just defines the idOne variable, not run the function (unless I am misunderstanding thsi whole thing which is possible).

Comment: @TomH `idOne` is *not* a reference to the setTimeout function. You can use it to cancel a timeout, but not start it again. You need two variables, just like this answer shows: one to start the timer, and one to stop it.

Comment: Although it looks like what you'll actually need is `setInterval` instead, but it's hard to say for sure from the example code.

Comment: I got it! I will update the main code to reflect it. Thanks a ton for your help everyone this was killing me for about 5 hours last night.